# ClassNotPersistenceCapableException

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm getting ClassNotPersistenceCapableException when trying to persist the following JDO class.

```
package com.xxx.cms.model;

import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text;

@PersistenceCapable
public class Transaction {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @Persistent
    private String type;

    @Persistent
    private Text details;

    @Persistent
    private Company client;

    @Persistent
    private Carrier carrier;

    @Persistent
    private Company sender;

    @Persistent
    private Company recipient;

    @Persistent
    private Customs customs;

    public Transaction(String type, Text details, Company client, Carrier carrier, Company sender, Company recipient, Customs customs){
        this.setType(type);
        this.setDetails(details);
        this.setClient(client);
        this.setCarrier(carrier);
        this.setSender(sender);
        this.setRecipient(recipient);
        this.setCustoms(customs);
    }
....
}
```

Then when I run the following:

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        try {
            pm.makePersistent(carrier);
            pm.makePersistent(sender);
            pm.makePersistent(recipient);
            pm.makePersistent(client);
            pm.makePersistent(cargo);
            pm.makePersistent(finance);
            pm.makePersistent(customs);

            Transaction transaction = new Transaction(transactionType, transactionDetails, client, carrier, sender, recipient, customs);        

            pm.makePersistent(transaction);
        } finally {


pm.close();
    }
```

I get the following exception in the app logs:

```
org.datanucleus.jdo.exceptions.ClassNotPersistenceCapableException: The class "The class "com.xxx.cms.model.Transaction" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found." is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data for the class is not found.
```

Any ideas why GAE is throwing this exception? The data from the other classes is persisted successfully as I can see it from the data viewer.

Comment: You need to check if you get some warning/error when applying enhancements for this class.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the exception
*"The class "com.xxx.cms.model.Transaction" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found."*

Which one of those possible options is true ?

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled as I've created the class by using the Google plugin for Eclipse, which does the binding automatically and handles the classpath too. So that leads me to the latter two possibilities, i.e. hidden by an unenhanced version, or meta-data/annotations for the class are not found... any suggestions how to determine which's causing the exception.

Comment: The Google plugin for Eclipse is nothing to do with DataNucleus so can't comment on what it does, just to say that DataNucleus provides its own Eclipse plugin for auto-enhancing classes and it certainly works. Are the classes enhanced ? look at them with a bytecode decompiler.

Answer (score 0):

I got this exact same exception when I started using Spring MVC in my GAE project. I was stuck, and almost decided to give up on GAE and Spring MVC until I found out that it was because I had been using the wrong version of a JAR. Quite a rookie mistake :(

I've put it down on my [blog](http://carlldev.tumblr.com/post/17290752821/datanucleus-enhancer) so that others can learn from this:

Answer (score 0):

This is becuse trying DataNucleus is trying to register an identical plugin. If you see console by stopping you local server, it will show as -

> DataNucleus Enhancer (version 1.1.4) : Enhancement of classes 
>   Encountered a problem: Unexpected exception  Please see the logs
>   [C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\enhance9016551549771995762.log] for
>   further information.

Then please check the log file ..

There error is highlighted as -

```
    Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. 
The URL "file:/C:/VB/Softwares/eclipse-jee-mars-1-win32-x86_64/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.30/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.30/lib/opt/tools/datanucleus/v2/datanucleus-core-3.1.3.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/C:/VB/Softwares/eclipse-jee-mars-1-win32-x86_64/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.30/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.30/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v1/datanucleus-core-1.1.5.jar."
```

Thus same jar datanucleus-core having two version.

> Now go to the path shown in error and Just delete the complete v1 folder as you have the latst v2 folder
>   with same latest jars and re-start your server, this will work....