# Does GAE support Spring-mvc and internal (to GAE) & external RESTFul web services calls

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine

I am planning migration to GAE a web app which is in jsp & java on top of Springframework's MVC mechanism. The interface between jsp and java is RESTFul web services, which could be part of my application, or provided by applications residing outside of GAE.

Based on reading of GAE introduction, I am under impression that neither RESTFul web services nor the said MVC mechanism is supported in GAE. However, I also saw a few Q&As here implying that Spring-mvc applications did work in GAE.

I must have missed something. May someone enlighten me?

Best Regards,

John Zhu

Answer (score 0):

AppEngine definitely supports RESTful web services using merely servlets and the low level APIs.  Frameworks are layers of abstraction on top of the same low level services. Unfortunately some frameworks fail to provide the full functionality available below because they aim for generality.  Frameworks sometimes add their own inefficiencies, for example the excellent [Autoscaling Java at Google IO 2013](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lFarE1hH0ss) presentation shows problems caused by Spring being used badly.

Searching StackOverflow for `[google-app-engine] Spring MVC` shows many references to working applications.  For example, you might pick up useful keywords from StackOverflow questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210546/classnotpersistencecapableexception) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13787857/spring-mvc-jsf-on-gae).